# Is this matrix field contractible inside the space of non-conformal matrices?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, matrix-calculus, svd

Set $\mathcal{NC}:=\{ A \in M_2(\mathbb{R}) \, |    \det A \ge 0 \, \,\text{ and } \, A \text{ is not conformal} \,\}$, where by a non-conformal matrix, I refer to a matrix whose singular values are distinct. (i.e. I allow non-zero singular matrices in $\mathcal{NC}$).

Let $A:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathcal{NC}$ be a matrix field defined as follows:

Described w.r.t the frame $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta},\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\}$,

$$ A(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta})=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}, A(\frac{\partial}{\partial r})=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+c\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta},$$

where $c>0$ is a fixed parameter.

> **Question:** Is $A:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathcal{NC}$ homotopic to a constant map?

Note that I define the range to be $\mathcal{NC}$. Of course, $A$ is null-homotopic when considering the range to be all $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

---

In matrix form,
$$[A]_{ \frac{\partial}{\partial r},\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ c & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

A computation shows that $A$ has the following form w.r.t the standard basis $e_1,e_2$:

$$A(\theta)=[A]_{e_1,e_2}=\begin{pmatrix} 1-\frac{c}{2}\sin(2\theta) & -c\sin^2(\theta) \\\ c\cos^2(\theta) &  1+\frac{c}{2}\sin(2\theta)\end{pmatrix}$$

i.e. this is $A(\theta) \in \mathcal{NC} \subseteq \text{Hom}(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^2)$.

I think that $A(\theta)$ may not be contractible, since from $\cos^2(\theta)$ we can compute $\cos(2\theta)$, which together with $\sin(2\theta)$ determines $2\theta$. (and the maps $\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ given by $\theta \to 2\theta$ is not homotopic to a point. However, I ask about $A$ as a map $\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathcal{NC}$; in order to get a map $\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$, we would need to compose it with some continuous map $\mathcal{NC} \to \mathbb{S}^1$.

---

*Here is what I know about the topology of $\mathcal{NC}$:*

Let $\mathcal D=\{ (\sigma_1,\sigma_2) \, | 0 \le \sigma_1 < \sigma_2\}$. Then the map

\begin{align*}
\mu: SO_2\times \mathcal D\times SO_2\to \mathcal{NC}\\
(U,\Sigma,V)\mapsto U\Sigma V^T
\end{align*}

is a $2$-fold smooth covering map*. (i.e. $\mu(U,\Sigma,V)=\mu(-U,\Sigma,-V)$, and this is the only ambiguity in $U,V$ for a pre-image of a given point in $\mathcal{NC}$.

Since $SO_2 \cong \mathbb{S}^1$, and since [after identifying antipodal points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561814/what-is-the-surface-obtained-by-identifying-antipodal-points-of-mathbbs1-t/3563215#3563215) in $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$, we get the $2$-torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ again, it follows that $\mathcal{NC} \cong \mathbb{T}^2 \times \mathcal D$.

*I am not entirely sure regarding the behaviour at the boundary points where $\sigma_1=0$, but I don't think this creates a serious problem.

Comment: You should explain what a matrix field is. Writing $A: S^1 \to \mathcal{NC}$ suggests that it is an ordinary map, but the definition seems to say that $A$ (**without** a parameter from $S^1$) is a a linear map from a tangent space of $\mathbb R^2$ to itself given in polar coordinates. May we take $A(\theta)$ = matrix in the line before "Here is what I know ..."?

Comment: Yes, you are right (I updated the question). This is exactly what I meant. BTW, I wonder if there is an argument which does not pass through the matrix representation of $A$ w.r.t the standard basis, but that uses only its more natural description in terms of the polar frame.