# Fundamental group of $\{\text{diag}(A,B) \colon A,B \in SO(2)\} /\{I,-I\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, orthogonal-matrices

Let $K=\{\text{diag}(A,B) \colon A,B \in SO(2)\}\subset SO(4)$, where 
$$ 
\text{diag}(A,B)=\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix}\text{.}
$$
What is the fundamental group of $K/\{I,-I\}$? Does this space have a name? Any information of this space is welcome.
I know that $PSO(4)=SO(4)/\{I,-I\}$ has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $\pi_{1}(PSO(2))=\mathbb{Z}$ so my first atempt was prove that $K/\{I,-I\}$ is homeomorphic to $PSO(2)\times PSO(2)$ but this is clearly not true.

Comment: More generally, the quotient of a torus by any closed normal subgroup is a torus (perhaps of smaller dimension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be mistaken here, but it seems that $K\approx SO(2)\times SO(2)\approx S^1\times S^1$ and that the map $K\to K/\{\pm I\}$ gives a fiber sequence

$$\{\pm I\}\hookrightarrow K\to K/\{\pm I\}$$

which we can right more topologically as a fiber sequence

$$S^0\hookrightarrow S^1\times S^1\xrightarrow q K/\{\pm I\}$$

(if you do not know about fibrations, then I am really just saying that $S^1\times S^1$ is a degree $2$ covering space of $K/\{\pm I\}$). Now, we know the univesal cover of $S^1\times S^1$ is $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\xrightarrow p S^1\times S^1$, so the universal cover of $K/\{\pm I\}$ is
$$\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\xrightarrow pS^1\times S^1\xrightarrow qK/\{\pm I\}$$
and we simply need to determine the fiber above a point. It is not hard to see that the fiber above the identity of $K/\{\pm I\}$ is, using more algebraic than topological notation,
$$(\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z)\cup(\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z+(1/2,1/2))=\mathbb Z(1/2,1/2)\oplus\mathbb Z(1,0)$$
and so we get that the $\pi_1(K/\{\pm I\})\simeq\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$ since it is $\pi_0$ of the fiber of $q\circ p$ which is the above discrete group.

Answer (score 3):

It is well-known that:

> Any compact, connected abelian Lie group is isomorphic to some $T^k$.

Now because $K$ is compact (why?), connected and abelian (why?), it must be isomorphic to $T^k$ for $k=\dim (K)= 1+1=2$. i.e. $K=\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1$.

Like @JasonDeVito's argument in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3563215/272127):

> $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\subseteq T^2$ generated by $\langle (\pi, \pi)\rangle$ (note that $-I\sim \tau(x,y):=(x+\pi,y+\pi)$) is normal (since $T^2$ is abelian, so we can form the quotient $K':=T^2/(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$).  Being the continuous homomorphic image of $T^2$, $K'$ must be a compact abelian Lie group, so it must be isomorphic to $T^2$ as a Lie group.  In particular, $K'$ is diffeomorphic to $T^2$.

So $\pi_1(K')=\pi_1(T^2)$.

Comment: Why is the dimension $4$?

Comment: Isn't $K\cong SO(2) \times SO(2) \cong S^1 \times S^1$?

Comment: I think I made mistake the order of matrix and dim of K. I'll fix it.

Comment: That looks better. Even though $SO(n)$ is a compact lie group of dimension $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ it only has rank $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$.