# Discrete subgroups of $\mathbb R^1\times S^1$ such that the quotient is compact

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, quotient-spaces

Let $\Gamma\leq\mathbb R\times S^1$ be a discrete subgroup such that $\frac{\mathbb R^1\times S^1}\Gamma$ is compact. Then what can $\Gamma$ be? Also, what are the possible results for the quotient space.

Intuitively, I think that for any $\Gamma$ with above properties, $\frac{\mathbb R\times S^1}\Gamma$ will always be diffeomorphic to the torus $S^1\times S^1$. Is that true?

Comment: Hint: This quotient is orientable, connected and has zero Euler chadacteristic.

Comment: Pull back to the universal cover. Do you know the classification of discrete subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: How do you compute the Euler characteristic without knowing its action?

Comment: Perhaps by $\dfrac{\mathbb R^1\times S^1}\Gamma \to \mathbb R^1\times S^1$?

Comment: If you are looking for a related post that you have answered, it is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3562898/272127)

Comment: @C.F.G By constructing an invariant nonzero vector field.

Comment: Interesting! Now how do you know that is invariant?

Comment: Alternative (but related) hint to what Moishe gave:  $\Gamma$ is normal, so $(\mathbb{R}\times S^1)/\Gamma$ is a compact abelian 2-dimensional Lie group.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: As usual, Common trick.  and the rest is similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3563215/272127)

Comment: @JasonDeVito: I know that there is a theorem that asserts that "the quotient of a
Lie group by a normal Lie subgroup is also a Lie group" but why it is compact?

Comment: @C.F.G:  That's the assumption on $\Gamma$ given by Chetan.

Comment: Aha. I am thinking around 1 hour that how to solve this!! So the compactness is in assumption. So in general it is not compact? any proper example?

Comment: @C.F.G:  Take $\Gamma = \{e\}$.  Less trivially, the $\Gamma$ where the quotient is *not* compact are precisely those which have trivial projection to $\mathbb{R}$.